# How to call the callback in a CakePhp Component?

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm using CakePhp 2.2 and I have this simple controller, named **ProvidersController**:

```
<?php

class ProvidersController extends AppController {

    public $components = array('Session', 'Social');

    public $layout = false;         

    public function facebook(){ 
    $this->Social->auth('facebook', 'success', 'error');
    $this->render(false);
    }

    public function google(){
     $this->Social->auth('google', 'success', 'error');
     $this->render(false);
    }

    private function success(){

    }

    private function error(){

    }

}

?>
```

and this Component, named **SocialComponent**:

```
<?php

class SocialComponent extends Component {

    public function auth($provider, $success, $error){

    }

}

?>
```

as you can see I have created success() and error() methods inside the controller. Now I pass these names and I would like to call them back from the component.

I only pass the name of the callback, how to call them from the component?

Thank you!

Comment: a) they are privat - no class on this earth except this very same one can actually call them   

b) your components should not trigger controller methods. it should be the other way around

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The point of a component is re-usability across many controllers - if you're trying to make it access a specific controller function, you should probably just be using controller methods, not a component.

BUT - you can always just do your logic in the component and pass back data (upon success or error), then check the results in the controller, and access whichever method you'd like based on those results.

Since your 'success' or 'error' logic is in the controller, I assume you don't want it in the component... ie it's different per use of the component.  In that case, all you really want the component to do is do the logic and let you know how it went (return data).

```
//Controller
//..
public function facebook(){ 
    $results = $this->Social->auth('facebook', 'success', 'error');
    if($results['error']) $this->Social->error();
    $this->render(false);
}

private function success(){ }

private function error(){ }
//...


//Component
//...
public function auth($provider, $success, $error){
    $results = array();
    //do something
    $results['error'] = true;
    return $results;
}
//...
```

Comment: While this is a valid solution to get the success/failure information back to the controller, the question explicitly asked about a detail in the callback pattern.

Comment: Wow, @pixelistik, you down-voted me AFTER he marked it as the answer?  That seems kind of low, don't you think?  I read the question, understood what he was hoping to achieve, and answered accordingly.  It's up to him if he thought my answer was helpful - obviously he did.  I also believe my answer will help the 99% who are trying to call a controller method from a component, when in reality, they would be better off doing what I suggested above.

Comment: I didn't mean to offend you. I was just going by the question and explained the reason why I think this is not quite the answer to it. And I've seen many times where the upvoted question differs from the one marked as correct.

Comment: @pixelistik - As I mentioned, this answer will help 99% of people who find this question (and it obviously helped the OP). It's a solid and helpful answer.  Please keep down-votes to yourself until you better understand the purpose of StackOverflow (to help others when they may or may not always know the best way to achieve something, and may not word their question "perfectly" in your eyes.)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [source code of the SecurityComponent](http://api20.cakephp.org/view_source/security-component#l-299) in CakePHP, it has an identical situation with its blackHoleCallback.

They use a helper function [`SecurityComponent::_callback()`](http://api20.cakephp.org/view_source/security-component#l-580) which uses PHP's [`call_user_func_array()`](http://de.php.net/call_user_func_array)

```
protected function _callback(Controller $controller, $method, $params = array()) {
    if (is_callable(array($controller, $method))) {
        return call_user_func_array(array(&$controller, $method), empty($params) ? null : $params);
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

You can use the same pattern to pass callbacks into your component.